# Anonymous type with counter for each result

Tags: c#, linq, counter, anonymous-types

Is it possible to have a counter going up when creating a Linq query returning an anonymous object?

E.g.

```
var results = from foo in bar select new { foo.ID, foo.Name, Counter = ???? }
```

I already tried defining a method which returns an increasing number, but the end result will be the same for all objects.

To clarify: I want the result to be

id, name, 1
id, name, 2
id, name, 3

Etcetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var counter = 0;
var results =
    from foo in bar
    select new { foo.ID, foo.Name, Counter = ++counter };
```

Answer (score 2):

With the [overload of `Select` that includes the index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) (also [available for queryables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx)) in fluent-syntax, you can do:

```
var results = bar.Select((foo, index) => new 
                                         { 
                                             foo.ID,
                                             foo.Name, 
                                             Counter = index + 1 
                                          });
```

Note that this overload is not available in query-syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
var result= db.bar.Select((foo,i)=>select new {foo.ID, foo.Name, Counter = i+1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the indexed Select() overload:

```
var results = bar.Select((foo, i) => new { foo.ID, foo.Name, Counter = i + 1});
```